# Segmentation fault after sudo commands

Tags: macos, segmentation-fault, sudo, su, sudoers

I've modified (in some wrong way) the file `etc/sudoers` in my Mac OS X 10.6.8.

For this reason I've erased the wrong line and replaced the original file. But now whenever I type sudo commands the output is:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 501, should be 0
Segmentation fault
```

A solution could be [this](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showpost.php?p=2680&postcount=2) but when I type `su` (and the password) the output is:

```
su: Sorry
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've followed [these steps](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528) to enabling and using the "root" user in Mac OS X.

In this way I can use the [fix](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showpost.php?p=2680&postcount=2) posted in my question.

Comment: once root user is enabled. you can use su root to login as root rather than sudo as root

Answer (score 7):

For the record, there is an easier way to fix this on OS X: run Disk Utility, select the volume in the sidebar, then the First Aid tab, and click Repair Disk Permissions.  /etc/sudoers is one of the system files it knows the "correct" permissions for, so it'll take care of it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This tool take a lot of time (22 minutes in my case) but it has found a lot of errors, so +1 =)

Comment: Usually, the problems permissions repair finds don't really matter; but just occasionally it'll fix something nasty (like this).  p.s. thanks @Bavarious.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to login as `root` directly, or boot into a `root` console, in order to change the ownership of the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: The same way you login in as any other user. (If you have automatic login and no manual login method, you'll have to boot into a `root` console.)

Comment: @Macmade if I type `su` I've the problem in the question. David, How can I boot into a `root` console?

Comment: [Boot into single user mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492) then [make the filesystems writable](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14484/mac-wont-boot-way-to-mount-drive-and-delete-one-file/14485#14485).

Comment: Ok after I boot on single user mode I type ’mount -o update /’ but the system returns: unknown flag '-o'

Comment: `/sbin/mount` is not recognized as an internal or external command, etc.

Comment: Thank you David, I've solved in [this way](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528) to use `su` command. +1 =)

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo -u root vim /etc/sudoers` , replacing 'root' with the user that you were logged in as when originally modifying `/etc/sudoers`. Then make any needed changes, save and quit, and try again.

I ran into this issue when adding `source ~/.bash_profile` to my ~/.bashrc file while logged in as root. Running `sudo -u root vim ~/.bashrc` as a non-root user and deleting the `source ~/.bash_profile` line fixed my issue.

Comment: I mistakenly added `source ~/.bashrc` to `/etc/bashrc`. With `sudo -u root vim /etc/bashrc` and removing the `source` line, the issue is fixed. Thanks @Ty Hitzeman.